# External configuration of Spring Cloud Function

Tags: spring, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-aws

I've been looking into solution wherein lambda function will use external configuration file from S3 on startup and make them available via placeholders ${} & Environment throughout the code base. I learned that s3://XYZ/test.yml works in Spring Cloud AWS so looking similar solution to retrive properties from S3 without downloading it to lambda environment. Please assist.